# Non-consuming regular expression split in Python

Tags: python, regex

How can a string be split on a separator expression while leaving that separator on the preceding string?

```
>>> text = "This is an example. Is it made up of more than once sentence? Yes, it is."
>>> re.split("[\.\?!] ", text)
['This is an example', 'Is it made up of more than one sentence', 'Yes, it is.']
```

I would like the result to be.

```
['This is an example.', 'Is it made up of more than one sentence?', 'Yes, it is.']
```

So far I have only tried a lookahead assertion but this fails to split at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import re

text = "This is an example.A particular case.Made up of more "\
       "than once sentence?Yes, it is.But no blank !!!That's"\
       " a problem ????Yes.I think so! :)"


for x in re.split("(?<=[\.\?!]) ", text):
    print repr(x)

print '\n'

for x in re.findall("[^.?!]*[.?!]|[^.?!]+(?=\Z)",text):
    print repr(x)
```

result

```
"This is an example.A particular case.Made up of more than once sentence?Yes, it is.But no blank !!!That'sa problem ????Yes.I think so!"
':)'


'This is an example.'
'A particular case.'
'Made up of more than once sentence?'
'Yes, it is.'
'But no blank !'
'!'
'!'
"That's a problem ?"
'?'
'?'
'?'
'Yes.'
'I think so!'
' :)'
```

.

### EDIT

Also

```
import re

text = "! This is an example.A particular case.Made up of more "\
       "than once sentence?Yes, it is.But no blank !!!That's"\
       " a problem ????Yes.I think so! :)"

res = re.split('([.?!])',text)

print [ ''.join(res[i:i+2]) for i in xrange(0,len(res),2) ]
```

gives

```
['!', ' This is an example.', 'A particular case.', 'Made up of more than once sentence?', 'Yes, it is.', 'But no blank !', '!', '!', "That's a problem ?", '?', '?', '?', 'Yes.', 'I think so!', ' :)']
```

Comment: @someone Thank you for the one who upvoted my answer that gives a correct result in all the cases (I hope) while some other impressionable-by-Matthew's-effect (I suppose it's the reason) people continue to upvote the other answer that gives correct result only for a limited case.

Comment: @eyquem Wauw, that's not really the way to induce sympathy. The simple answer gives the correct result for a limited case *which* matches exactly what OP requested. It's easy to introduce further complexity (in scenario as well as solution), especially for regex-related questions, but not always does the added complexity serve any purpose (or have a hold in the real-world requirements). In order words: Your indentified shortcomings in the other answer *may* be valid, but it's really only for OP to decide.

Comment: @jensgram I think that a good answer can't merely answer to the delimited case considered in a question . It's a matter of love of good code and of respect for the person who questioned and that may not think to all the particular, but not rare, cases that a solution will practically encounter.

Comment: @jensgram I don't agree with your expression _"It's easy to introduce further complexity"_ 1) Because it's not a matter of introducing, it's a matter of the reality : _"90% of coding is debugging. The other 10% is writing bugs. Bram Cohen."_ So an interesting answer is one that widen the context of the question by giving ideas to which the person who questioned didn't think and that warns her/him of the potential bugs.

Comment: @jensgram  I don't pretend that I always do that : very often, the lack of sufficient information in the question discourages to do a developed answer because it would be a too dense one, considering too much possibilities; or I have not enough time or I am not very much inspired, or etc. But I don't start with the idea that minimalist answer is always the best.

Comment: @jensgram 2) Because it is much more easy to do a laconic answer than to try to taking account of the potential complexity of the real-world requirements, that exist despite what we would like. On the other point , I agree with you _"Your indentified shortcomings in the other answer may be valid, but it's really only for OP to decide"_ , but to decide, he must be aware of them, and I think it's better to warn him about the potential shortcomings than letting him to practically bump into them at any moment

Comment: @jensgram Concerning the fact that my comment doesn't induce sympathy, it's a problem indeed. Think that this comment is only one among others that I could do but that I don't really write because I fear to be reproached to write non sympathic stuff. But must we always hide the truth behind such considerations ?

Comment: @jensgram By the way, remark that I don't precisely criticize the other answer in fact , but rather the upvoters that seem to me to be quick to react without a lot of reflection. -*- Moreover, I could write something else, but I don't dare to do it. If you write me at eyguem@gmail.com (with eyGuem, not eyQuem !) , I will say it to you. Anyway, thank you for your point-of-view and reflection.

Comment: @eyquem as much as you do sound like a bit of a hissy little girl, I have to admit you put me closest to the final solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Rob Young _"you do sound like a bit of a hissy little girl"_ I wonder why. Thank you for the upvote and acceptation of the answer.

Comment: @eyquem why not just "[^.?!]*[.?!]" ?

Comment: @bcorso Because, **concerning the regexes, there is often a specific problem at the end of a string**. Here, the pattern ``[^.?!]*[.?!]`` requires that after a substring matched by ``[^.?!]*``, there must be one character ( any of the set ``[.?!]`` ) : then if the analysed string ends on a character that isn't one of this set, the last substring that should be matched wouldn't be.

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> re.split("(?<=[\.\?!]) ", text)
['This is an example.', 'Is it made up of more than once sentence?', 'Yes, it is.']
```

The crucial thing is the use of a *look-behind* assertion with `?<=`.

Comment: +1, after careful consideration ;-). I, too, think that a terse answer can be better, as it highlights the important thing.

Comment: @all @ThomasH I draw the attention of the ten upvoters so far that they have upvoted an answer that is wrong: the separator used in this answer is a blank and this blank isn't kept in each separated string, contrary to the crucial demand of the OP. ThomasH, I draw your attention to the fact that an answer, even if it is terse, can't be a better one if it is a wrong one.